# Caching ASP.NET Menu control

Tags: asp.net, caching, menu

I use a System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu to build and present a user menu. Loading the menu requires considerable database activity and takes about 1.4 seconds, so I am looking for ways to cache the menu across page turns. If I keep a SessionVariable["ThisMenu"] that contains the menu control, the value of ThisMenu is correct across page turns; however, I cannot set the actual control on the page successfully.

If I try this code, it compiles and executes, but nothing appears in the HTML output:

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu ctlMasterMenu = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu)GetControl("ctlMasterMenu");
if (ctlMasterMenu != null)
{
    if (ThisMenu != null)
    {
        ctlMasterMenu = ThisMenu;
    }
    else
    {
        LoadPageMenu((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu)ctlMasterMenu); // Sets ThisMenu
    }
}

If I try this code, it executes, but as it adds a MenuItem to ctlMasterMenu, it removes the item from ThisMenu. The result is that after a few page turns, the menu is empty.

System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu ctlMasterMenu = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu)GetControl("ctlMasterMenu");
if (ctlMasterMenu != null)
{
    if (ThisMenu != null)
    {
        List<MenuItem> items = new List<MenuItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < ThisMenu.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            items.Add(ThisMenu.Items[i]);
        }
        ctlMasterMenu.Items.Clear();
        foreach (MenuItem item in items)
        {
            ctlMasterMenu.Items.Add(item); // Causes item to be removed from ThisMenu
        }
    }
    else
    {
        LoadPageMenu((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu)ctlMasterMenu);
    }
}
```

There must be a simple way that works.

Answer (score 1):

Consider caching or reworking your database query. Caching the menus will likely result in storing additional data on the server or client via ViewState. The source of your menus is your data so you should start there.

Comment: I am caching the results of the database query, but processing those result is what takes the time. I understand the ViewState hit, and I want to avoid that as well. Right now I am getting the worst of both worlds. It's an ASP control, so it winds up in ViewState AND I rebuild it from the cached query. I wish it would just persist.

Comment: Bob, does the "LoadPageMenu" method take 1.2 seconds? It would be interesting to see that code.

Answer (score 1):

Store the actual data that builds the menu in cache, and build the menu every time from this cached data.  Disable viewstate to save on performance.  Don't store the menu or menu items themselves.

Comment: That is exactly what I am currently doing, but it takes almost 1.2 seconds to regenerate the control... hence this post. I want to find out how to cache the control as well.

Comment: @BobJones Is that the code above?  Why then are you clearing items from the list?  If you disable viewstate, and add the items on every postback, that should be faster.  If not, the other alternative is that you can bind it to XML, as mentioned here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecs0x9w5(v=vs.80).aspx  So you can convert it to XML the first time, then onpostback, try converting it.